# I am looking the author of specific position

Tags: study, identify-this

Who is the author of this study?

```
[FEN "q7/8/8/6R1/7R/k7/P7/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a correction of study by Luigi Centurini that was published in [Schachzeitung, vol. 8, i. 10 (Oct., 1853), p. 333:](https://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno-plus?aid=szb&datum=1853&page=349&size=45) "White moves, but can only draw." The original setting was:

```
[FEN "q7/8/8/8/8/8/6RR/k6K w - - 0 1"]
```

(Note that a very closely related study with the same material but with a 'White wins' stipulation appears on p. 332.)

According to Harold van der Heijden's chess study database, which probably incorporates the Arves source cited by another poster it was corrected
(M. Garcia & M. Campioli in Estudios Artisticos de Ajedrez - XVII-21 2015), but I have not seen that correction myself.

(Note: That other post seems to have gone away as I was adding this reply?  Pity -- the alternate source it gave would have been useful, as it may have been the original publication.)

(Added: after getting a link to the [www.arves.org web site](https://www.arves.org/arves/index.php/en/halloffame/550-centurini-luigi-1820-1900) cited in the deleted post I find that the web page did not provide any more useful source information, but seems to be a selection from van der Heijden's database, release V. The front page I thought could have been the original publication was from a book on rook endgames published in 1853.)

Added:  The author, then, would be Garcia & Campioli, after Centurini, or some similar writing.  Centurini didn't author the position, but neither did Garcia & Campioli create it independently of Centurini.

Comment: The deleted answer's link for you: https://www.arves.org/arves/index.php/en/halloffame/550-centurini-luigi-1820-1900